# Read and Update Azure AD B2C extension attributes

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have a trust framework SignUpOrSignIn custom policy user flow which sets 3 extension attributes for an app.
I can see these 3 claims and their default values in the token.
However, when I `GET` the user via MS Graph API (`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{tenantId}/users/{userId}`), I do not see these extension attributes.
Once I `PATCH` the user, I can then see the value via the `GET` to the {userId} segment as expected.

**PATCH**

```
{
    "extension_{appId}_subscription_expiry":"2020-04-10"
}
```

Why are any extension attributes not returned until they've been subsequently `PATCH`ed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have set default values for the 3 extension attributes in your custom policy, you can only see them in the token after your sign-up at that time. But you didn't store them into Azure AD.

I guess that you just add such a code `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_subscription_expiry" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="xxx" />` in your `SignUpOrSignIn.xml` file.

But if you want to store the values into Azure AD, you should write the custom claim to the user profile by using `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail` TechnicalProfile. See [Read and write a claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input#read-and-write-a-claim).

You should finish all the steps listed in this document: [Add claims and customize user input using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input)

Comment: Allen Wu I have a very similar problem I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile as suggest by you but I have a validation problem

Comment: @Balint Can you post a new issue including all the details so that I can look into it?